# Can't switch to NVIDIA GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, gpu

My laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 has switched to Intel GPU after a reboot.
I am not quite sure what did cause this as I reboot almost once a week.
I've noticed the FPS drop, and ran `screenfetch`, saw output `GPU: intel`.

- My GPU: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
- Proprietary NVIDIA driver (nvidia-driver-390) is installed and selected
- NVIDIA GPU is chosen on `nvidia-settings`
- I've tried setting it to Intel, and then back to NVIDIA

Some outputs:

```
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: the nvidia profile is already set

$ sudo nvidia-settings
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).
** Message: 15:01:48.861: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 15:01:48.861: PRIME: is it supported? yes

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
#(the application starts)

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ loginctl show-session c1 -p Type
Type=x11
#(I disabled Wayland to see if it fixes the problem) 

$ lspci | grep "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

How do I make NVIDIA GPU work again? Thanks!

Edit: uninstalled CUDA, and every NVIDIA package, then installed driver back again. Worked!

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia driver?  The Ubuntu packages come with glue scripts to rebuild the Nvidia driver for each new updated kernel .  Other install methods may not, so you need to repeat the reinstallation yourself.

Comment: I've tried `apt-get purge*` & `apt-get install nvidia-390` and 396 but it didn't work. I've solved it by uninstalling CUDA, and installing two nvidia-something-390 packages. I'm not sure what they were, as I probably installed driver 30 times in 6 hours :D